# Azure Active Directory - Graph API request additional field

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm using the Graph API to pull down information about a specific user in my organization.  This works great, however one piece of information I need is the users "Security Groups" from their Active Directory account.

I use the following URL to request the Graph API information for a given Active Directory objectID.

```
https://graph.windows.net/[domain]/users/[objectID]?api-version=1.5
```

This gives me an JSON result that contains the users information such as their Department, jobTitle, userPrincipalName, etc.

How can I also request the users Security Group memberships? Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are available on the `memberOf` navigation property. So you can make a call to this:

`https://graph.windows.net/[domain]/users/[objectID]/memberOf?api-version=1.5`

[User entity documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#user-entity)

Comment: brilliant!  Thank you!  Completely overlooked it.